# asp.net loading bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

I have code in my Page_load method that can take up to a few seconds to fetch back the data and store it into a table.

How can I display a percentage (or just generic) loading bar until all the data is ready, as oposed to just having the empty table until the data is ready?

Is there an asp control dedicated to progress bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to show the data, you may use ana ajax call to server on the dom ready If event and show it

```
<div id="myTableDate"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
   //Whatever inside this block will be executed once DOM finishes loading
   $("#myTableDate") .html("Loading data....").fadeIn(100,function(){
      $("#myTableDate").load("getdata.aspx");
   });    
});

</script>
```

And you should have a getdata.aspx page which returns the HTML markup you wish to display.

You may alternatively use `ashx` handlers to get the HTML Markup data. (this is my preference)

This solution needs [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) library to be included in your page.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: *you can't*. A possibility would be to break-up the tasks that are performed in `Page_Load`, call them synchronously using Ajax while updating a progress bar client-side.